# using linebreak in action mailer on the @body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

i have build some website that take a message and send it to email recipient,
the user can send emails by typing the message and the recipient.
my issue is when a user type :
"My \r\n name \r\n is \n user"
the emails that have been sent is ignoring the linebreaks, or any html code inside the message, how can i support it ?

this is the html that have been sent:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body >
    <h3>Hi <%= @user.username %>,</h3>
    
      <%= @message %>


    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple_format did the trick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body >
    <h3>Hi <%= @user.username %>,</h3>
    
      <%= simple_format(@message) %>


    
  </body>
</html>
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FTextHelper%3Asimple_format